# Address already in use:9001 while running multiple API

Tags: microservices, port

I have opened 3 different APIs in 3 different consoles of Intellij. One API is dependent on the other so I need to run the 3 at the same time. Three APIs are REST APIs created in spring boot project. When I am running one after the other I am getting the exception below.

```
> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:491)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:180)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:836)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:381)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:135)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
    ... 11 more
```

My APIs will run in three different `server.port`s.

Comment: Hi. You can modify the `server.port` property in your application.properties or application.yml file of Spring Boot project for all the three different APIs to run on non-conflicting ports.

Comment: @NayabSiddiqui  I have already mentioned API's are running in 3 different ports .I have configured as you mentioned. But after doing also i am getting same exception.

Comment: Strange. By any chance are the previous processes already running and have not been terminated ? It might happen if you've closed your IDE and didn't opt for terminating the processes.. try running lsof command and see if there are ports occupied already ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the **server.port** but the port on which the JMX Beans are running/listening.
If you are using Maven you can configure this in the spring-boot-maven-plugin with

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <jmxPort>9009</jmxPort>
        </configuration>
        ...
```